# App crashes on kitkat but not on lollipop

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using a simple listview in my app .
In my adpater I am resizing the elements. It works fine when I run it on Nexus5(Lollipop) but crashes on Moto E(Kitkat).

My adpater is

```
      package com.hj.app.adapters;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

 import com.hj.app.R;
 import com.hj.app.holders.HJFeedItemViewHolder;
 import com.hj.app.objects.HJFeedItemObject;


public class FeedListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<HJFeedItemObject> objects;

Context mContext;

public FeedListViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.objects = new ArrayList<HJFeedItemObject>();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects == null ? 0 : objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.hj_feed_recycle_item_layout, null);
        HJFeedItemViewHolder holder = new HJFeedItemViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    HJFeedItemViewHolder holder = (HJFeedItemViewHolder) convertView
            .getTag();
    holder.feedTitle.setText(objects.get(position).getFeedTitle());
    holder.feedPostTime.setText(objects.get(position).getFeedGenTime());
    holder.sourceUserName.setText(objects.get(position).getFeedSourceObj()
            .getUserName());
    holder.sourceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        if (position % 3 == 0) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mContext.getAssets().open(
                    "houzz1.jpg"));
        } else if (position % 3 == 1) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mContext.getAssets().open(
                    "houzz2.jpg"));
        } else {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mContext.getAssets().open(
                    "houzz3.png"));
        }
        LayoutParams lp;
        if (bitmap.getHeight() < 900) {
            lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 900);
        } else {
            lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    bitmap.getHeight());
        }
        holder.feedPicFrame.setLayoutParams(lp);

        holder.feedPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    lp1.bottomMargin = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(
            R.dimen.hj_margin_large);

    if (position == 0) {
        lp1.topMargin = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(
                R.dimen.hj_margin_large);
    }
    holder.feedParent.setLayoutParams(lp1);
    if (objects.get(position).isFeedFav()) {
        holder.favorite.setSelected(true);
    } else {
        holder.favorite.setSelected(false);
    }
    holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.isSelected()) {
                v.setSelected(false);
                objects.get(position).setFeedFav(false);
            } else {
                v.setSelected(true);
                objects.get(position).setFeedFav(true);
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

/**
 * @param itemObjs
 */
public void addData(ArrayList<HJFeedItemObject> itemObjs) {
    objects.addAll(itemObjs);
}
```

}

I am getting the following error

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

Please help

Comment: use `import android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams;` instead `import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;`

Answer (score 0):

Check the

```
    android:minSdkVersion="##"
    android:targetSdkVersion="##"
```

on manifest

for kitkat , the SDKVersion is 21

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  importing android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams; change import to => import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

And where ever you are setting layout params do like this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp1 = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams
(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Use following links to properly use view holder pattern
http://ricston.com/blog/optimising-listview-viewholder-pattern/
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html